# Using the Rally Java Rest API, how do I get DirectChildrenCount?

Tags: java, api, rest, rally

I seem to be able to get all the other attributes but this one.  I get DirectChildrenCount: null in the console when I query for this attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you fetch DirectChildrenCount, the next thing to verify is the version of Java Rally REST tookit that you're using and the WS API version you specify in the code.

Here is a code example that prints out DirectChildrenCount.

It uses rally-rest-api-1.0.7.jar, which works with the latest WS API v2.0

If you are using rally-rest-api-1.0.6.jar it should still work as long WS API version is set correctly in the code, for example:

```
String wsapiVersion = "1.43";
```

It will return DirectChildrenCount: null when using rally-rest-api-1.0.6.jar if you do not specify the version or specify a version below 1.39.
DirectChildrenCount was introduced in 1.39.

If you are using rally-rest-api-1.0.7.jar, it defaults to v2.0 of WS API, so the code below will work and DirectChildrenCount will be returned even if WS API version is not set in the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

    // Create and configure a new instance of RallyRestApi

    String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
    String username = "user@domain.com";
    String password = "secret";
    String wsapiVersion = "v2.0";
        String workspaceRef = "/workspace/1111";
    String projectRef = "/project/2222"; 
    String applicationName = "DirectChildrenCount";


        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                new URI(host),
                username,
                password);
        restApi.setWsapiVersion(wsapiVersion);
        restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);   


        QueryRequest storyRequest = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");
        storyRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name","DirectChildrenCount"));
        storyRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
        storyRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "US16"));

        QueryResponse storyQueryResponse = restApi.query(storyRequest);
        JsonObject storyJsonObject = storyQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
        System.out.println(storyJsonObject.get("Name") + " DirectChildrenCount: " + storyJsonObject.get("DirectChildrenCount"));
    }
```